# Java Application + Subpixel Rendering

Tags: 11.04, java, subpixel-rendering

How i can enable subpixel rendering in java applications like NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret [this blog posting](http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/lcd_sub_pixel_rendering) correctly, then subpixel rendering should automatically be available with Java 6 runtimes, unless you are using a Mac. If so, this posting has instructions how to re-enable it there.

I'm running Eclipse with a Sun Java 6 runtime and did not have to manually enable subpixel rendering, but that may be something different as Eclipse uses SWT graphics library while NetBeans uses Swing.